# do we need PHP encoder or php decoder to install magento extension

Tags: php, extensions

we bought an extension. they gave source files. but some files are in encrypted manner.

that extension files are encrypted.

they mentioned we need php encoder[8.3] to install the extension in the site.

do we need to install "PHP ENCODER" or "PHP DECODER" to get the extension work in server?

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: well...install php encoder, what ever that is. On the other hand, I would not install the extension. it means that the code is not open source and it can hide harmful stuff.

Comment: is php encoder is free ? can't we use php decoder to work that extension in our server?

Comment: What extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the module requires ionCube, in which case you will not be able to use the module without installing ionCube on the server.

I've never looked into it, but whilst there may theoretically be a way to decode / reverse engineer the encoded files, this would certainly be against the license of the module you purchased.

Whilst I understand the position of developers trying to protect their work, IonCube encoded modules are best avoided wherever possible. It makes customisation of the module next to impossible, you can't tell what the code does, meaning theoretically there could be backdoors or nefarious code. Even compatibility with different versions of PHP can't be determined without testing. Should you discover it doesn't support PHP 5.4 for example, you can't even patch it.

Comment: can we use ion cube loader to get the code source? is we mandatary required ion cube encoder only? if so, what is the codt price of ion cube encoder..
please give me some guidance....

Comment: No. You cannot (legally) get the actual PHP code. If you wish to use the module you must leave the encoded code as is and install ion cube decoder on the server. You only require the ion cube **decoder** in order to run the code. This is free. You don't need the **encoder**.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply.

fine, if we install decoder, that's enough for module to work, but if we want the source code than only 

we need encoder ? am i right?

Comment: I say again, you CANNOT get the source code. The **encoder** is used exclusively by the people that made the module to encrypt the code in the first place.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i am getting some error in admin panel : " Request authentication failed"

do you think it;s related to decoder?

Comment: The module likely requires you to enter a license in the admin panel. Either that or they encrypt modules specifically based on the domain, and the module you have isn't for the domain you are trying to use it on.

Comment: they asked for our domain name and  told they configured for our domain name : www.example.com, in that case is the licence key is just enough to run the module for our domain?

Comment: but on the official module page, they mentioned we need "php ioncube encoder to run the module".... so i got a problem....

right not module is not working....  Request authentication failed error on shipment page when we click on" 
submit shipment button"...

Comment: but eventhough we enter a licence key, we should need php loader on ther server, am i right?